# Find number of days from two dates using shell

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to find number of days from two given dates as 25 Aug 2017 and 05 Sep 2017.

My script:

```
start='2017-08-25';
end='2017-09-05';
ndays=(strtotime($end)- strtotime($start))/24/3600;
echo $ndays
```

When run this script, I am getting following error messages.

```
Line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Desire output value:

```
10
```

Comment: Shouldn't it print 11 instead of 10?

Comment: It depends on the hours. In my case it starts from `00 Hours of 25 Aug 2017` to `00 Hours of 05 Sep 2017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No shell that I am aware of has any tools for working with dates. At the very least, you need an external tool like `date` to convert your dates to an intermediate form, like the number of seconds since some fixed point in time (Unix uses Jan 1, 1970), then do your calculation with those values before processing the result further.

Assuming the use of GNU `date` from the Linux tag, you would do something like

```
start='2017-08-25'
end='2017-09-05'

start_seconds=$(date +%s --date "$start" --utc)
end_seconds=$(date +%s --date "$end" --utc)

ndays=$(( (end_seconds - start_seconds) / 24 / 3600 ));
echo $ndays
```

Note that since most shells only support integer arithmetic, this won't give you an exact number of days.

Comment: Added the `--utc` option so that when `start=2019-03-09 end=2019-03-11`, the result is 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date` to convert each date to epoch seconds, then use arithmetic expansion to do the subtraction and conversion back to days:

```
#! /bin/bash
start='2017-08-25';
end='2017-09-05';

diff=$(date -d $end +%s)-$(date -d $start +%s)
echo $(( ($diff) / 60 / 60 / 24 ))  # 11
```